# Adding floats does not yield a correct result

Tags: c#, .net, double, floating-accuracy

Imagine the following situation.
Amounts are added to a total in a loop:

```
float total = 0;
float[] amounts = new float[]{...};
foreach(float amount in amounts)
{
  total += amount;
}
```

`total`, as wel as all the `amount`s are written to a database.
When I calculate `SUM(amount)` in SQL, it results in a value that differs from `total`.
Moreover, when I do the same calculation in C#, but this time adding the amounts to a value of type double,

```
double total = 0;
//the rest of the code is the same as above
```

then `total` represents the correct value.

Could this be caused by the difference in precision between a float and a double?

Note that it depends on the values. Most of the results of this calculation *are* correct.

Comment: A variable of type float only has 7 digits of precision where as a variable of type double has 15 digits of precision.

Comment: Show us the floats and then we would be able to help...?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance: the values are random (not as in "randomly generated", but they can be anything)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. SQL Server's float size is variant but you likely have 8 byte floats in the database. When you use doubles ( 8 bytes ) in the C# code the results are the same, when you use floats ( 4 bytes ) they're different. double values within the range of a float will not be the same as the float values.

Comment: I should mention that they are stored as `real` in SQL Server. But even then the sum (of `real` values in SQL) is more accurate than the sum of `float` values in C#.

Answer (score 3):

> Could this be caused by the difference in precision between a float and a double?

Yes. It can also sometimes simply be because *not all values can be represented* in an IEEE floating point; in many scenarios where you expect "exact" sums (money, etc), it is usually better to use `decimal`. However, that shouldn't to be interpreted to mean that `decimal` is "exact" - simply that the way it rounds is more conducive to how we humans think of rounding.

Comment: Is it correct to say that `decimal` is *more* exact because it uses even more bits (than `double` to represent a value?

Comment: One thing that can be surprising about .NET's `System.Decimal` is that it sometimes uses 29 decimal digits, and sometimes 28. For this reason calculations like `800m/3m * 3m` and `500m/3m * 3m` which people _expect_ are equivalent, are not similar (guess which one is an integer (with trailing zeroes)).

Comment: @BartVG It's more _precise_ because of that.

Comment: @BartVG `double` can represent much larger and much smaller values; it has more *range*, but less *precision*; http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75(v=vs.110).aspx vs http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9(v=vs.110).aspx