# C# Threading - thread only runs properly when breakpoint exists

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms, visual-studio

I've been having trouble getting the below C# threading code to behave properly. I start a thread by clicking a button on a form, and the thread simply declares a float `x` and increments it in a loop until `threadRunning` is set to false. I set `threadRunning` to false when I click the button again. When the loop completes, the thread sets `threadResult` to the incremented value `x`. I then display `threadResult` on the form.

The problem is that `threadResult` always gets set to 256.0 in this case. If I choose to increment `x` by `0.0001f`, then `threadResult` will always get set to 2048.0. These fixed values are assigned to `threadResult` every time the thread runs.. *unless* I put a breakpoint on the incremented line, `x += 0.00001f;`. This can be a conditional breakpoint with the condition set to false; as long as an enabled breakpoint exists on this line, `x` is incremented properly and gets assigned to `threadResult`.

---Edit 1---
To clarify what proper behavior is, which occurs only when an enabled breakpoint exists on the incremented line: `threadResult` gets assigned a value equal to the number of times the incrementing line is hit multiplied by the increment value. So, if `x` was incremented 121 times, and the increment value is 0.00001f, `threadResult` should become 0.00121. This *does* occur when an enabled breakpoint exists on the incremented line and I'm running in debug mode.

Also, when I run this in release mode, the program hangs when I click the button to stop the thread, so I'm assuming something is wrong with my threading implementation entirely. I would still appreciate any pointers on what might be the problem with my code. I just wanted to write something to test stopping a thread. Also, I don't want to use BackgroundWorkers, because my threading code isn't intended to be used with Windows Forms.
---End Edit 1---

Can anyone explain to me what is going on here? Is the method that I use to stop the thread okay, by setting the thread's loop control variable to false outside of the thread? I've tried this code in Visual Studio 2017, 2015, and 2013, all with the same result.

Here is the code. The form contains only a button named `button1` and a textbox named `textBox1`.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace ThreadingTesting
{
   public partial class Form1 : Form
   {
      public Form1()
      {
         InitializeComponent();
         button1.Click += Button1_Click;
      }

      private Thread thread;
      private bool threadRunning = false;
      private float threadResult = 0;

      private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
         if (threadRunning)
         {
            threadRunning = false;
            thread.Join();
            textBox1.Text = "Result: " + threadResult.ToString("N4");
            button1.Text = "Start Thread";
         }
         else
         {
            thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadedWork));
            thread.Start();
            textBox1.Text = "Thread Started!";
            button1.Text = "Stop Thread";
         }
      }

      private void ThreadedWork()
      {
         threadRunning = true;
         float x = 0.0f;
         while (threadRunning)
         {
            x += 0.00001f;
         }
         threadResult = x;
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Try looking up the keyword `volatile`.

Comment: `thread only runs properly when breakpoint exists` What is the improper behaviour you are seeing? What is the proper behaviour you are seeking?

Comment: If your trying to not block the UI you should look into `async`/`await`

Comment: I think you will find that 256 is the value where adding 0.00001f has any affect at floating point accuracy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Adding floats does not yield a correct result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17373909/adding-floats-does-not-yield-a-correct-result)

Comment: Neither the threading code nor the math code is correct here. Threading logic and floating point arithmetic are both tricky and require considerable knowledge to get correct. Do not make the variable volatile; **learn why it is that if you have to make a variable volatile to fix a threading problem, you are probably solving the problem with the wrong tool**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`256 + 0.00001f` unfortunately results in `256`. This is why it never proceeds past 256.

Consider using `double` (`d`) rather than `float` (`f`).

Comment: Or better - `decimal` (M). `256M + 0.00001M`.

Comment: Okay, using `double` works. I must not have changed all doubles when I made my first edit. This still doesn't explain why it works with `float`s only when a breakpoint exists.

Comment: @bgg That is because you have two threads reading and writing to the same non-`volatile` variable without a memory barrier (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3493931/why-do-i-need-a-memory-barrier). Would you consider using `BackgroundWorker` instead?

Answer (score -1):

the answer is here

[Why Thread.Join() DOES NOT hang my application when called on UI thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38911758/why-thread-join-does-not-hang-my-application-when-called-on-ui-thread)

the method Button1_Click is called in UI Thread and so the other thread will not run properly.

I think than you have to approach Task or BackgroundWorker...